# Fine time blowup: Existance of solution

Tags: analysis, dynamical-systems

Consider

> $\dot{x}=x^{3}, x \in \mathbb{R}, x(0)=1$. T     his is solved by $x(t)=$ $1 / \sqrt{1-2 t}$, so $x \rightarrow \infty$ when      $t \rightarrow \frac{1}{2}$.

I have the following theorem for uniqueness [image]

My task is to explain why there is no contradiction.

**My reasoning:** Clearly the conditions for the uniquness theorem hold. What is happening is that  we get a small neighbourhood about $t_0=0$ on which the solution exists and is unique, say $(-\delta_1,\delta_1)$. Now I can apply the theorem again but this time with $t_0 = \delta_1 / 2$. I can continue this process to get a unique, continuous solution onto $(0, \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the supremum of the (\delta_i) in this process. What is happening above is that this supremum is $1/2$, and so we can't use the uniqueness theorem at $1/2$ itself.

**Question:** Is my reasoning correct?

**Edit: Additional Context**
(1) will be the ode mentioned in the first definition bellow. All other terms should be bellow too.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have not shown us what system $(1)$ looks like. That theorem is obviously being stated with some standard notation / setup in mind, but we don't know what it is. Maybe we can guess, but it's better to make the post self contained

Comment: @FShrike apologies, I haven now eddited the post. Please let me know if there is any ambiguity.

Comment: Hmm. It's kinda sloppy, we should require some topological properties on $E$. The uniqueness theorem is false e.g. if $E$ is a singleton because then $f$ is not defined on any neighbourhood of $x_0$

Comment: I don't even see why we're supposed to think there's a contradiction. The 'theorem' states a unique solution exists on a neighbourhood of $0$, and we've been presented with a solution that exists on a neighbourhood of $0$. No indication has been made that this solution is non-unique, so, there is absolutely nothing that challenges the theorem statement

Comment: I should mention that this is in the context of a course on Dynamical Systems so I am not sure what detail is required.

Comment: This is one of those questions where you (unfortunately) have to read the instructor's mind. There is no obvious contradiction. The best you can do is talk about the Lipschitz condition being satisfied. The theorem avoids discussion about the maximal interval of existence, so it doesn't even make sense to talk about that. All you can seemingly say is that it is consistent with the theorem since the theorem only talks about local existence/uniqueness.